# SQL Server Linked Server Update - terrible performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, linked-server

In my SQL Server 2012 database, I have a linked server reference to a second SQL Server database that I need to pull records from and update accordingly.

I have the following update statement that I am trying to run:

```
UPDATE
    Linked_Tbl
SET
    Transferred = 1
FROM
    MyLinkedServer.dbo.MyTable Linked_Tbl
JOIN 
    MyTable Local_Tbl ON Local_Tbl.LinkedId = Linked_Tbl.Id
JOIN 
    MyOtherTable Local_Tbl2 ON Local_Tbl.LocalId = Local_Tbl2.LocalId
```

Which I had to stop after an hour of running as it was still executing.

I've read online and [found solutions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4428/performance-issues-when-updating-data-with-a-sql-server-linked-server/) stating that the best solution is to create a stored procedure on the Linked Server itself to execute the update statement rather than run it over the wire.

The problems I have are:

1. I don't have the ability to create any procedures on the other server.
2. Even if I could create that procedure, I would need to pass through all the Ids to the stored procedure for the update and I'm not sure how to do that efficiently with thousands of Ids (this, obviously, is the smaller of the issues, though since I can't create that procedure in the first place).

I'm hoping there are other solutions people may have managed to come up with given that it's often the case you don't have permissions to make changes to a different server.

Any ideas??

Comment: The solution is definitely to create your procedure on the target server that queries the source on the local server, rather than the procedure locally sending updates remote. If you are unable to do this you are going to get RBAR updates to the linked server (I don't think there is any way around this). Don't think there is a workaround. To answer your #2 it is far more efficient to select the IDs from the linked server than it is to send each row individually as part of the remote update.

Comment: Don't need to create a stored procedure at the remote server. Just use a piece of dynamic SQL containing the update, so you just run the code with `EXEC AT` and the remote server does everything. Have a look here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec527f63-d454-4b8a-81e9-23a2ff54c1ca/execute-at-with-dynamic-linked-server-name?forum=transactsql

Comment: @Alejandro, thank you, this seems like the only real way around this... I'm not a HUGE fan, but it seems like the best alternative given this situation.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, whether it can give more performance, you an try:

```
    UPDATE
    Linked_Tbl
    SET
    Transferred = 1
    FROM OPENDATASOURCE([MyLinkedServer],'select Id, LocalId,Transferred from remotedb.dbo.MyTable') AS Linked_Tbl
    JOIN MyTable Local_Tbl
    ON Local_Tbl.LinkedId = Linked_Tbl.Id
    JOIN MyOtherTable Local_Tbl2
    ON Local_Tbl.LocalId = Local_Tbl2.LocalId
```